# How do I append printed lines from console into a QPlainTextEdit with python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, sys

So I have this problem, I need to update the QPlainTextEdit with all the printed lines from the console.

```
class Ui_logWindow(QtCore.QObject):

logSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
parsedLogSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
# output_GUI = ''
critical = True

def showLogs(self):
    self.critical = True
    self.q = queue.Queue()
    arg1 = self.lineEdit.text()
    arg2 = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
    arg3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    arg4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    arg5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
    arg6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
    self.client = ClientLogParser(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
    self.client.client.on_message = self.onMsgWin
    self.logSignal.connect(self.appendLog)
    self.appendLogSimple = self.logSignal.emit
    self.parsedLogSignal.connect(self.appendParsedLog)
    self.appendLogParsed = self.parsedLogSignal.emit
    self.t = Thread(target = self.client.startListen, args=[])
    self.t.daemon = True
    self.t.start()
    self.t2 = Thread(target = self.processMsg, args=[])
    self.t2.daemon = True
    self.t2.start()

def submit(self):
    self.showLogs()

def appendLog(self,msg):
    self.log.appendPlainText(msg)

def appendParsedLog(self, msg):
    self.parsedLog.appendPlainText(msg)

def onMsgWin(self, client, userdata, msg):
    self.listMsg = msg.payload.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    self.q.put(self.listMsg)
    
def processMsg(self):
    while self.critical == True:
        try:
            self.listMsgProcessed = self.q.get(self.listMsg)
        except:
            sleep(.1)
        else:                
            self.appendLogSimple(self.listMsgProcessed)
            for line in self.listMsgProcessed.split('\n'):
                self.client.lp.parseEvent(line)
                self.client.rp.evaluateDict(self.client.lp.dictLogs)
                # self.output_GUI += "START\n"
                print('Start')
                for key, val in self.client.lp.dictLogs.items():
                    print(f"EVT : [{key}]")
                    # self.output_GUI += f"EVT : [{key}]"
                    if val == 1 :
                        # self.output_GUI += f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] time \n'
                        print(f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] time')
                    elif val > 1:
                        # self.output_GUI += f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] times \n'
                        print(f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] times')
                print("RULES:")
                # self.output_GUI += "RULES:\n"
                for rule_idx in range(len(self.client.rp.dictRulesList)):
                    print(f"RULE : [{rule_idx}] [{self.client.rp.dictRulesList[rule_idx]}]")
                    # self.output_GUI += f"RULE : [{rule_idx}] [{self.client.rp.dictRulesList[rule_idx]}]\n "
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'warning':
                        print(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]")
                        # self.output_GUI += f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'info':
                        print(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]")
                        # self.output_GUI += f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'succes':
                        print(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]")
                        # self.output_GUI += f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'critical':
                        print(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]")
                        # self.output_GUI += f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                        print(f'Action critical triggered.')
                        # self.output_GUI += f'Action critical triggered.\n'
                        # self.appendLogParsed(self.output_GUI)
                        self.critical = False
                print('End')
                # self.output_GUI += "END \n"
                # self.appendLogParsed(self.output_GUI)

def setupUi(self, logWindow):
    self.log = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 20, 1250, 311))
    self.log.setReadOnly(True)
    self.log.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
    self.log.setMaximumBlockCount(15)
    self.parsedLog = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.parsedLog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 350, 1660, 640))
    self.parsedLog.setReadOnly(True)
    self.parsedLog.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
    self.parsedLog.setMaximumBlockCount(50)
```

I have put only the needed code here. As you see I tried to create # output_GUI = '' var which will take the text and append it to it and than append this to the QPlainTextEdit but this is working too slow if lines are coming fast and the lines comes fast.
So as you see the first QPlainTextEdit is self.log, everything works fine here, because it just put the log in the box, but I don't know how to take all the print from def.processMSG(self) and append them in self.parsedLog. How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I, solved it :

I've created a self.output = StringIO() object and than replace print with StringIO().write see example bellow:

```
def processMsg(self):
    while self.critical == True:
        try:
            self.listMsgProcessed = self.q.get(self.listMsg)
        except:
            sleep(.1)
        else:            
            self.output = StringIO()    
            self.appendLogSimple(self.listMsgProcessed)
            for line in self.listMsgProcessed.split('\n'):
                self.client.lp.parseEvent(line)
                self.client.rp.evaluateDict(self.client.lp.dictLogs)
                self.output.write('Start\n')
                for key, val in self.client.lp.dictLogs.items():
                    self.output.write(f"EVT : [{key}]\n")
                    if val == 1 :
                        self.output.write(f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] time\n')
                    elif val > 1:
                        self.output.write(f'[{key}] has been triggered [{val}] times\n')
                self.output.write("RULES:\n")
                for rule_idx in range(len(self.client.rp.dictRulesList)):
                    self.output.write(f"RULE : [{rule_idx}] [{self.client.rp.dictRulesList[rule_idx]}]\n")
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'warning':
                        self.output.write(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n")
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'info':
                        self.output.write(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n")
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'succes':
                        self.output.write(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n")
                    if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'critical':
                        self.output.write(f"RESULT : [{rule_idx}] action changed [{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n")
                        self.output.write(f'Action critical triggered.\n')
                        self.critical = False
                self.output.write('End \n')
                self.contents = self.output.getvalue()
                self.output.close()
                self.appendLogParsed(self.contents)
```